# Accommodating a Q.all in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I swear by Q for its simplicity, so I might not have done much research checking out other 'then' implementations. But I've used Q a good deal!

I have a chain of 'then' promises, and I want to resolve a 'batch' of promises in the middle of it and proceed with other operations in sequence; so it's obvious I should use Q.all. But I'm stuck here. Either Q's doing it wrong, or I am.

Here are two hypothetical async operations

```
var f=function(delay){
  return Q.delay(delay).then(function(){
    console.log("returning delayed",delay)
    return delay
  })
}

f2=function(delay){
  var defer=Q.defer()
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("returning timedout",delay)
    return delay
  },delay)
  return defer.promise
}
```

And this is the promise chain

```
  Q('begin')
    .then(console.log)
    .then(Q.all([100,200,300,400].map(f)))
    .then(function(){
      console.log("Finally",arguments)
    }).done()
```

And this is the output I wish

```
begin
returning delayed 100
returning delayed 200
returning delayed 300
returning delayed 400
Finally { '0': undefined }
```

But this is the output I get

```
begin
Finally { '0': undefined }
returning delayed 100
returning delayed 200
returning delayed 300
returning delayed 400
```

I get the same sequence with `f2`

Now, if I run this

```
Q.all([100,200,300,400].map(f)).then(function(){
  console.log("Finally",arguments)
}).done()
```

I do get

```
returning delayed 100
returning delayed 200
returning delayed 300
returning delayed 400
Finally { '0': [ 100, 200, 300, 400 ] }
```

but using `f2` instead of `f` gives me

```
returning timedout 100
returning timedout 200
returning timedout 300
returning timedout 400
```

It doesn't execute the `finally` block.

I get the same outputs with Q.[all/allResolved/allSettled]

So, my queries are,

1. How do I achieve the intended output by using Q.all specifically. I do  have a workaround though, but it doesn't look nice.
2. How are `f` and `f2` different since the results by running Q.all().then() with them aren't the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Q.all` takes an array of promises, but then *returns* a promise (that is the only resolved when every promise in the array is resolved.

So, I think you need to return the result of `Q.all` in order to not immediately call the next `then`:

```
Q('begin')
    .then(console.log)
    .then(function() {
        return Q.all([100,200,300,400].map(f));
    })
    .then(function(){
      console.log("Finally",arguments)
    }).done()
```

Comment: Perfect solution for my problem as well!

Answer (score 2):

Answering the second question, your usage of `f2` is incorrect.

When you create a promise using a deferred you must resolve it in order for it to become fulfilled. You can read more about it in [How to convert a callback API to promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

In your case you're creating an empty deferred and returning its promise but you never actually call `.resolve` on the deferred. Doing it "more correctly" would be something like:

```
f2=function(delay){
  var defer=Q.defer()
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("returning timedout",delay)
    defer.resolve(delay); // note the resolve here vs the return
  },delay)
  return defer.promise
}
```

Using `Q.delay` works better since it's already promisified. As for other `then` implementations Q is hardly bleeding edge right now to say the least :)